# leaks command not detecting memory leaks in C program

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, heap-memory

I have a C program where I suspect the presence of memory leaks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *f()
{
    return (char *)malloc(10);
}

int main()
{
    f();
    system("leaks a.out");
    return 0;
}
```

The **`f()`** function allocates 10 bytes of memory using **`malloc`**, but I don't free it before the program terminates. Despite using the "leaks" command in the terminal, it does not report any memory leaks.

I also tried adding a delay with **`sleep`**, hoping it would allow the "leaks" command enough time to detect leaks, but no leaks were detected.

Why is the "leaks" command failing to detect memory leaks in this scenario? Are there any alternative methods or tools I could use to effectively identify memory leaks in my C program?

thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe you should do something with the allocation to be sure that the call to `f()` doesn't get optimized away.

Comment: that's what i wanted to know , is there in optimization in this case . @adabsurdum

Comment: I am not familiar with the leaks program but it is rather unlikely that it works the way you are trying to use it. You probably should remove the ine with a call to `system` and instead run something like `leaks ./a.out` from the command line.

Comment: @Elhazin -- inspect the assembly code to see if `f` is called. I compiled your program with gcc, and with optimizations at `-O2` the call to `f` was optimized away. Or just use the allocation, e.g., put a string in it and print it out, to be sure that it won't be optimized away.

Comment: yes , I printed a string  in the function and it was printed so the function is called @adabsurdum

Comment: Is a leak detected when you run `leaks a.out` from the command line as @n.m.willseey'allonReddit suggested? Alternative tools: [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 0):

A compiler may optimize away the call to `f()` (and with that the call to `malloc`) since you never use the return value from `f` and nothing in `f` has any other noticeable side effects. gcc for example compiles the program into this:

```
f:
        mov     edi, 10
        jmp     malloc
.LC0:
        .string "leaks a.out"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    system
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

... and as you can see, there's no call to `f` from `main`.

If you make `f` `static`, a compiler could also be sure that it doesn't need to keep `f` in there at all and remove it completely:

```
.LC0:
        .string "leaks a.out"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    system
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```